# MVC 4 Web Api Odata $Filter issues

Tags: asp.net, backbone.js, asp.net-web-api

I have a problem which I cannot seem figure out. Your help will be much appreciated. I am using the Odata Nuget package. Now I have this url:

```
localhost:3196/api/leads/get/?$filter=DateSent+gt+datetime'2012-09-06'
```

Works perfectly. If I have the following

```
http://10.211.55.4:3196/api/leads/get/?$filter=DateSent+gt+datetime'2012-09-06'&_=1349632487099
```

I get this error - **')' or operator expected at position 16 in '(_ eq 'datetime'1349632487099')'.** Before I installed the package the following worked.

```
http://10.211.55.4:3196/api/leads/get/?$filter=(DateSent+gt+datetime'2012-09-06')&_=1349632487099
```

Still no luck however. Could you help? By the way if I put the filter at the end of the url it works. This is not ideal. Backbone automatically attaches the cache variable and I dont want to overwrite/hack this.

Thanks

Tyrone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried this and it seems to work fine. From the error message, it appears that the url is not being encoded properly. Also you mentioned that putting the $filter at the end seems to work which could as well mean that there is something wrong with the url encoding. Is that possible ?